# Query yields syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

Running this MySQL query in PHP yields a syntax error I can't solve.

```
function queryTest(array $dataArray)
    $query = "Insert into users (email,fullName,password, accessLevel) values (($dataArray['formEmail']),($dataArray['formFullName']),($dataArray['formPassword']),($dataArray['formAccessLevel']))";                                                   

    if( $this->mysqli->real_query($query)) == FALSE
    {
        throw new exception ("failed");
    }  
}
```

Error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), 
>       expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number 
>       (T_NUM_STRING) in /home/comp3170-036/public_html/lab2/Registration.php on line 148

Comment: You're passing arrays; the quotes are causing that. Show us where `$dataArray` is coming from and what you're trying to pass as values. Do ` var_dump();` and see what's going through and tell us what it is.

Comment: this is a function in my class. I want to pass a $_POST array to it (the parameter variable data array). So  once i create the object I will do that. Will do var dump now,

Comment: Try removing the quotes for `['formEmail']` and the others while escaping your data. Show us a sample of what you're trying to pass as data.

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '==' (T_IS_EQUAL) in /home/comp3170-036/public_html/lab2/Registration.php on line 148 .................And e,g Ben Rich, bet@gmail.com,dasds,CEO

Comment: When comparing against FALSE, it is usually 'correct' to use triple equal:  `===` .

Comment: Change `if( $this->mysqli->real_query($query)) == FALSE` to `if( $this->mysqli->real_query($query) == FALSE)` - If that works, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your INSERT query seems to be wrong:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

Answer (score 0):

You probaly have an error in your query, check your last column name. Whitespace are not directly allowed :

`$query = "Insert into users (email,fullName,password, access level)`

Answer (score 0):

For debugging issues like this, `echo` or `vardump` the contents of `$query` before submitting to the database. That will show you the actual SQL text that is being submitted to the database.

It looks like one of the problems is that single quotes are missing around literals in the values list. It also looks like this code is vulnerable to **SQL Injection**.

Best practice is to *not* include data values in the SQL text, but to instead make use of **prepared statements** with **bind placeholders**.